# Python: check if all points within a rectangle

Tags: python, for-loop, boolean

I wrote below function to check if the list of points is within a rectangle, and it should return True only if all points in the list are in the rectangle.

```
def allIn(firstCorner=(0,0), secondCorner=(0,0), pointList=[]):
    if len(pointList) == 0:
        return False
    for i in range(0, len(pointList)):
        if (secondCorner[0]>=pointList[i][0]>=firstCorner[0] and secondCorner[1]>=pointList[i][1]>=firstCorner[1]):
            return True
        elif (secondCorner[0]>=pointList[i][0]>=firstCorner[0] and firstCorner[1]>=pointList[i][1]>=secondCorner[1]):
            return True
        elif (firstCorner[0]>=pointList[i][0]>=secondCorner[0] and secondCorner[1]>=pointList[i][1]>=firstCorner[1]):
            return True
        elif (firstCorner[0]>=pointList[i][0]>=secondCorner[0] and firstCorner[1]>=pointList[i][1]>=secondCorner[1]):
            return True
    return False
```

The coordinates of firstCorner and secondCorner just defines one of the corners of the rectangle, do not always represent the top left corner of the rectangle and the bottom right corner.

However, the result always comes back as True. The only time it will return False when the coordinate which is not in the rectangle is the first element in the list.

For example: firstCorner = (0,0), secondCorner = (5,5), pointList=[(1,1), (0,0), (5,6)] (which (1,1) and (0,0) are in the rectangle while (5,6) is not)

print(allIn((0,0), (5,5), [(1,1), (0,0), (5,6)])) always returns True, same result for print(allIn((0,0), (5,5), [(1,1), (5,6), (0,0)])). It only returns False when I put the list as print(allIn((0,0), (5,5), [(5,6), (1,1), (0,0)]))

Could anybody help me to find out which part is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that you put "return False" in "for" statement?(place 1 in below code ?)

```
def allIn(firstCorner=(0,0), secondCorner=(0,0), pointList=[]):
    if len(pointList) == 0:
        return False
    for i in range(0, len(pointList)):
        if xx
            return True
        elif xx
            return True
        elif xx
            return True
        elif xx
            return True
        return False  # place 1,here ? cause what you say 
    return False  # or here ?
```

additionly, if the real code is same as that in your question, it also be wrong,
because the code realize "or" logic ,i.e. if exist any one point in rectangle, it will return True .
here is my code:

```
def allIn(firstCorner=(0, 0), secondCorner=(0, 0), pointList=[]):
    ret=[]
    if len(pointList) == 0:
        return False
    for i in range(0, len(pointList)):
        if (secondCorner[0] >= pointList[i][0] >= firstCorner[0] and secondCorner[1] >= pointList[i][1] >= firstCorner[
            1]):
            ret.append(1)
        elif (secondCorner[0] >= pointList[i][0] >= firstCorner[0] and firstCorner[1] >= pointList[i][1] >=
              secondCorner[1]):
            ret.append(1)
        elif (firstCorner[0] >= pointList[i][0] >= secondCorner[0] and secondCorner[1] >= pointList[i][1] >=
              firstCorner[1]):
            ret.append(1)
        elif (firstCorner[0] >= pointList[i][0] >= secondCorner[0] and firstCorner[1] >= pointList[i][1] >=
              secondCorner[1]):
            ret.append(1)
        else:
            ret.append(0)

    print("ret:",ret)
    return all(ret)
```

Comment: Yes, I tried to put return false at both places, but neither of that worked. I realized that it might be picking up "or" logic because when I changed code from returning True/False to print "True/False", I got the result as True, True, False. But I didn't know how to fix it to make it boolean based on the overall result of checking all those points. Your code works perfectly. Thank you so much.